# SCons building with non-standard location of boost library

Tags: c++, boost, scons

We install various boost versions in a non-standard location.

We then modify `CPPPATH` and `LIBPATH` to reflect the selected boost version. However, some boost headers do not get picked up by the scons Scanner and so they do not get copied into the variant output location.

The reason they are not picked up by the scons Scanner is because they use macros like the following:

```
#include BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_HEADER(boost/atomic/detail/caps_)
```

This leads to file not found errors during compilation.

How do we modify the scons scripts so that they copy the entire boost library over?

I looked into the Depends() routine, but this requires a target node, which we do not have handy at the time we bring in Boost into our build system.
This is because all our 3rd party libs are wrapped with a library level SConscript, which basically establishes which version of the 3rd party lib should be used `(CPPPATH,LIBPATH)`. When that libs `SConscript` is read, no target nodes are available to it, as this is done very early on in the `SConstruct` process.

Thoughts on how to solve this?

Here is our `SConscript` for `"declaring"` Boost to our environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

Import('env')

PROJ         = 'boost'
TARGET       = PROJ
VERSION      = '1.57.0'
PATH_INCLUDE = 'cmn/thirdparty/boost/' + VERSION + '/include'
PATH_LIB     = 'cmn/thirdparty/boost/' + VERSION + '/lib'


## extend/modify the imported environment
if not PROJ in env['THIRDPARTY']:
  env['THIRDPARTY'][PROJ] = { 
    'TARGET'       : TARGET,
    'VERSION'      : VERSION,
    'PATH_INCLUDE' : PATH_INCLUDE,
    'PATH_LIB'     : PATH_LIB,
}

  ## because boost emits lots of warnings when compiled under c++11, we use the -isystem flag to disable the warnings
  env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-isystem', os.path.join(env['BUILD_ROOT'], PATH_INCLUDE)])
  env.PrependUnique(CPPPATH = [ os.path.join(env['BUILD_ROOT'], PATH_INCLUDE)])
  env.PrependUnique(LIBPATH = [os.path.join(env['BUILD_ROOT'], PATH_LIB)]
```

Comment: I've not observed scons to ever copy files found through CPPPATH - though we generally use it with `duplicate=False` anyway

Comment: Also, you're both adding the include path manually to CCFLAGS to get rid of the warnings, *and* to CPPPATH? Are you sure that works the way you intend?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the entire boost into your variant dir?

Comment: @Melak We add the path to -isystem as a CCFLAGS. This disables warnings. This has worked fine for us.

Comment: @bdbaddog  We don't *need* to copy the entire Boost lib to the variant dir, but because the Scanner isn't detecting certain include files (because a MACRO is used), they don't get copied over, so we only get partial copy of the set of header files we need.

Comment: I'm asking if adding it to CCFLAGS *and* CPPPATH is wise.

Comment: I think @bdbaddog is asking if you need *any* boost headers copied to your variant dir at all.

Comment: @melak  That's what we're moving away from. We have strict controls in our organization, so upgrading system libs is a laborious inter-departmental process, let alone upgrading our deployed environment in the remote data center. We are trying to shift towards checking in thirdparty prebuilt libs like boost into our SCM tool. This prevents developers from getting "off track" since it's baked into our source tree. We even checked in scons into our source tree allowing us to upgrade w/o needing root permissions on each developer workstation (something developers do not have)

Comment: We also check in some of our toolchains :)  Let's continue this [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104567/room-for-melak47-and-rkemp) maybe?

Comment: Hi @melak47, unfortunately our web filtering wont' allow me to access the chat. Let me see if I can get IT to open up the URL.

Comment: If you're not packing up and shipping the boost header files, then don't copy them. Just point to them wherever they are and use them. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: @bdbaddog We aren't shipping boost headers, but we are the libs!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Add a 2nd Append to CCFLAGS for 'SRC_ROOT'

```
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-isystem', os.path.join(env['SRC_ROOT'], PATH_INCLUDE)])
```

I could just use the single Append above (for SRC_ROOT) by itself, but I was still seeing warnings (and copying of Boost files into the variant dir), so I needed both -isystem paths to avoid massive warning output.

SRC_ROOT is the root of our src tree.
BUILD_ROOT is the root of the variant dir.

NOTE: You can remove the CPPPATH, since it's ignored by gcc when the same path in used for -isystem